# Laravel-Debugbar not catching AJAX call (Angular call)

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, phpdebugbar

I am working on project which front end is AngularJS & Backend is Laravel4.

And I am using barryvdh's [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) package as debugger

My problem is debugbar showing data when first time load page or i refresh page

But is is not catching when i call api throw angular resourse.

I tried AJAX call configuration as posted in documentation but still not working.

In config file:-

```
/*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Capture Ajax Requests
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | The Debugbar can capture Ajax requests and display them. If you don't want this (ie. because of errors),
     | you can use this option to disable sending the data through the headers.
     |
     */

    'capture_ajax' => true,
```

And In My Controller:-

```
        Debugbar::addMessage('Another message', 'mylabel');
        Debugbar::warning('Watch out..');
        Debugbar::sendDataInHeaders();
```

-ND

Comment: Show us your configuration.

Comment: @Kasyx I have updated , Now see this

Comment: Have you read this? http://phpdebugbar.com/docs/ajax-and-stack.html#ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching longtime on web i got solution for this problem

Kindly add this code to your app.js

```
  .factory('httpInterceptor', function($q) {

        var handle_phpdebugbar_response = function(response) {
             if (phpdebugbar && phpdebugbar.ajaxHandler) {

         var headers = response && response.headers && response.headers();
                if (!headers) {
                     return;
                 }

        var headerName = phpdebugbar.ajaxHandler.headerName + '-id';
               var debugBarID = headers[headerName];
               if (debugBarID) {                           
                     phpdebugbar.loadDataSet(debugBarID, ('ajax'));
                 }
             }
       };

            return {
                request: function(config) {

                    return config || $q.when(config);

                },
                response: function(response) {

                    if (response || $q.when(response)) {

                        handle_phpdebugbar_response(response);
                        return response || $q.when(response);
                    }


                },
                responseError: function(response) {

                    handle_phpdebugbar_response(rejection);
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };
        })
```

```
     .config(function($httpProvider) {

            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

     })
```

This one is in angular module  [ng-phpdebugbar](https://github.com/connyay/ng-phpdebugbar)

Comment: I tried using same code and also tried via module with Angular it gives me error "phpdebugbar is not defined". Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

**(Laravel5)**

Instead of returning your response, send it to a view:

```
return \View::make('debug', ['data' => $response]);
```

instead of

```
return response()->json($response);
```

(don't forget to create the view where you echo your data)